# Why isn't the function public boolean accept(File dir, String name) invoked in Android?

Tags: java, android

I use listFiles function in the utility https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

The `Utility.LogError()` will log a string, the result of the following is below, it seems that both `Utility.LogError("BB2: ")` and  `Utility.LogError("DD2: ")` aren't invoked, why?

AA2
CC2
AA2
CC2
AA2
CC2
AA2
CC2

```
   final File f = new File( FileFolderHelper.GetListDiskPath().get(0),"DCIM");


    Collection<File> aa=FileUtils.listFiles(f,

            new IOFileFilter() {
                @Override
                public boolean accept(File file) {
                    Utility.LogError("AA2: ");
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                    Utility.LogError("BB2: ");
                    return false;
                }
            },

            new IOFileFilter() {
                @Override
                public boolean accept(File file) {
                    Utility.LogError("CC2: ");
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                    Utility.LogError("DD2: ");
                    return false;
                }
            }
         );
```

Comment: because the code inside `FileUtils.listFiles()` is not calling `accept()` version that has `String name` parameter, only the one with `File file` version, i think there should be another version (overload) for `FileUtils.listFiles()` that takes beside of the `File` parram a `String` which is the name to filter listing files based on, if so then i think this version `accept(File dir, String name)` will be called

Comment: Thank! but I can't find  another version (overload) for FileUtils.listFiles() that takes beside of the File param a String which is the name to filter listing files based on,

Comment: could be available in other version of apache commons? i am not sure

Comment: Did you mean that other version will have different result?

Comment: no i mean other versions of JAR file may contain other overloaded methods for `listFiles()`

Comment: But it seems that it doesn't contain other overloaded methods for listFiles() !